# How to redefine the names for the standard keywords in C#

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I have the interesting idea. I want to redefine the keywords in C#, like replace the `if` keyword to the `MyIf` or something else. Do someone have any idea about how to do it?

As I think it have to look something like this:

```
namespace
{
   #define MyIf = if;
   #define MyElse = else;
   ...

   public someclass
   {
        public void someMethod()
        {
            MyIf(true)
            {
               ...
            }
            MyElse
            {
               ...
            }
        }
   }
}
```

**Added:**

Maybe there is the way how to make the C++ or **C** library which will redefine the part of standard core of C#?

**Notice. I know that it is the bad programming practice and I ask all the programmers to not use the answer in your enterprise code. **

Comment: Don't do that. It makes your code unmaintainable.

Comment: It's an interesting question though

Comment: why do you need your own `if`? what should it do different from the standard `if`

Comment: It's just the question for fun. I understand that this is a bad programming practice.

Comment: Yap i want to know it too

Comment: You can't. C# does not support any form of macros.

Comment: It is probably not possible **because** it is a bad idea.

Comment: Nice question but why you want to do that

Comment: Nemerle which is strongly based on C#, can do this.

Comment: Fixed your question, it is not operators, but keywords.

Comment: You can create your own pre-processor for C# code files.

Comment: oh yes, leppie thx. I'm pretty bad in english. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not possible -- C# does not have a preprocessor like C and C++ do, so there is no mechanism to transform the source before the compiler sees it. And of course the compiler will only recognize the standard `if`, so there is also no other option that somehow transforming the source before the compiler sees it.

Even if it were possible, it would be just a step below Cthulhu in the horror scale.

Comment: You are wrong in C# there is a preprocessor:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx

Comment: @Maris: Preprocessor directives does not imply C# has a preprocessor.

Comment: @Maris: The page you linked to says "Although the compiler does not have a separate preprocessor, the directives described in this section are processed as if there were one."

Comment: Oh, yes. I missed it. Let's w8 for any other idea how to do it. ) Maybe someone have ideas.

Comment: @Maris: Like I said in the comments, Nemerle can do this. Nemerle can even compile normal C# code.

Answer (score 4):

In c# you can override the overloadable operators (**+** , **-** , **==**) more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(v=vs.80).aspx

But you **can't** really override conditional operators.

The same goes for these operators =, ., ?:, ->, new, is, sizeof, typeof, they cannot be overloaded.

C# does not support macros, but of course you could write a custom parser that handles macros before eventually sending your code to the c# compiler, take a look at **Microsoft Roslyn** for that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx

Comment: Why a custom parser or Roslyn? I simple find/replace will be just as good with C#.

Comment: find/replace isn't always a good solution, roslyn is really easy to use, so I would use it. I wrote some code that extracted sql queries out of 10GB TFS collection , took me 20 mins to write to code, and a couple of minutes for my program to extract the queries.

Comment: You would have to change `MyIf` to `if` before Roslyn will parse it. Then it will be the same as C#. What are you suppose to do with Roslyn then? I get your comment, I just dont understand the use-case of Roslyn with regards to the question.

Comment: as I said before find/replace isn't a good solution, dunno if it's just me, but I don't like that approach. 

When using Roslyn, I can tell it to look for some specific code in a method body or in a using declaration, I can be more specific.. I think it's a good idea.

Comment: You dont get my point. Roslyn will not be able to parse `MyIf`. So if you do that beforehand with find/replace or a custom C# parser, how does Roslyn help with it? Why do you even need it then?

Comment: before doing a replace I would have used Roslyn to specify where the replace should be done, as I don't want to replace everything, including comments etc, I want be specific to method bodies. Do *you* get it now?

Comment: So you are saying Roslyn will correctly parse the OP's snippet? Even though it is nonsensical in terms of C#?

Comment: no, I'm not saying that, you would have to do a replace / parsing or whatever inside a method body. What I say is that roslyn can be combined with a custom parser / replacer or whatever lol

Comment: And how long would this take you? You are basically writing a custom C# compiler. Sounds like a lot of effort for not much gain.

Comment: No, nothing like that, I would've done that in a couple of minutes, let's end this conversation, it's going nowhere.  :-)

Comment: Feel free to do this in a few minutes and get back to me once you are done. I will be impressed if you can :)

Comment: Not negative, just realistic having written many parsers and compilers in the past. Maybe if you dont have time, can you point me to a working example of how it is done (the few minutes way).

Comment: don't know of no working examples, but I'm sure someone has done it before too. I have also written a lot of compilers and work on daily basis with cil and c# compilers, so I'm also pretty realistic about that. Have a great day

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Monads** with **`extension methods`** like so...

this is Monad Maybe

```
    public static TInput If<TInput>(this TInput o, Predicate<TInput> evaluator)
        where TInput : class
    {
        if (o == null) return null;
        return evaluator(o) ? o : null;
    }

        public static TResult Return<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator, TResult failureValue)
            where TInput : class
        {
            if (o == null) return failureValue;

            return evaluator(o);
        }
```

// the using

```
var result = ListOfObjects.If(o => o.Id == 1).Return(x => x.Object, null);
```

Comment: +1. This doesnt look like the answer on the question. But I like this  idea. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you it's was taken from the idea of Monad Maybe if you like it i can post the whole class

Comment: Post it please. I think that it will be usefull for a big amount of people. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redefine `if` or `else`, because C# doesn't have a preprocessor that would enable you to do something like that (probably also to prevent anyone from doing things like that).

But you can redefine when instances of your classes evaluate to `true`/`false` (it's the closest you can get):

```
public static bool operator true(YourType x)
{
    return x.IsLying ? !x.Whatever : x.Whatever;
}

public static bool operator false(YourType x)
{
    return x.IsLying ? x.Whatever : !x.Whatever;
}
```

Example:

```
YourType wah = new YourType() { IsLying = true, Whatever = true };
if (wah) {
    // ...
}
else {
    // ...
}
```

See here for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx

Answer (score 1):

### C# [#define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The #define lets you define a symbol, such that, by using the symbol as the expression passed to the #if directive, the expression will evaluate to true.

C# doesn't have a [preprocessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx), but it has alike directives:

> Although **the compiler does not have a separate preprocessor**, the directives described in this section are processed as if there were one. They are used to help in conditional compilation. **Unlike C and C++ directives, you cannot use these directives to create macros**.

So it is not the same #define as in C++ or C. C# #define only states that there exists a literal but there is no replacement or macro for that literal.

```
#define STRING int // Valid in C++ but invalid in C#
```

---

### C++ [#define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> **The #define directive substitutes token-string for all subsequent occurrences of an identifier in the source file**. The identifier is replaced only when it forms a token. (See C++ Tokens in the C++ Language Reference.) For instance, identifier is not replaced if it appears in a comment, within a string, or as part of a longer identifier.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, preprocessor directives are there for conditionally-compile code.

[For example:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> `#define`  lets you define a symbol. When you use the symbol as the expression that is passed to the `#if` directive, the expression will
>   evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

Do something similar to what you want, you could override the implicit bool operator:

```
using System;

class PleaseDontDoThis {
    public static implicit operator bool(PleaseDontDoThis h) {
        return (new Random().Next() % 2 == 0);
    }
}

static class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var x = new PleaseDontDoThis();
        if (x) {
            Console.WriteLine("true");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("false");
        }
    }
}
```